# How to dynamically generate target files for a cycle?

Tags: salesforce, informatica-powercenter

I have source file as follows:

```
ID    Name
1     A
2     B
3     C
4     D
5     E
```

...so on.

Data should go to 3 target files:
I want first 3 records to be routed to first target file, next 3 to second target file and so on till 9th record.
After that, next 3 records (10th-12th) should be routed to 1st Target file again.
This should go on for n number of records.
There will be 3 Target Files, mapped multiple times.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Create a port that will have target file name. Set the target to append to file. Use `Transaction Control` to start writing to next file.

Answer (score 0):

For this to achieve my approach would be to use  Mod of id\3. Below is how I would handle it in expression:

Variable port v_mod: MOD(ID,3)--- finds mod and its value would be 0,1,2 always

variable port group: IIF(ISNULL(group) OR  group= 0 OR v_group=4,1,v_group)-- sets the variable port group to 1 at initialization or if group value increases by 3 i.e 4

Output port o_grp: group-- output port

v_group=IIF(v_mod=0,group+1,group)-- increase value of group which can be used in variable port group.

After this is performed o_grp output port can be used in router to divide the rows to multiple target based on value i.e. either 1,2,3